# Git pull not working correctly?

Tags: git, github

I had a very weird experience with Git today. My project has a database dump on GitHub. Today there were some changes made to the dump repo on GitHub on the develop branch. I pulled the changes (`git pull origin develop`) and updated my local database with the changes. For some reason I still had the previous version of the DB rather than the new one. I checked the SHA in `git log` and it was the correct SHA (the latest SHA). When I used vim to inspect the contents of the file it was the older file.

I tried to pull several more times each with the same result.  Finally I ran

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

(a different branch)
then did

```
git pull origin develop
```

and the SHA was the same (the latest SHA) but the file was the correct file this time (the latest file as expected).

I was and still am completely perplexed by what could have caused this. Can anyone offer insight into what may be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: What was saying git status? I guess that depending on your configuration, if you have local modification pull will not attempt to merge to avoid overwriting them (not sure)

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Moulard mentioned in the comments, if you have local, uncommitted changes in your working directory, and you pull/merge changes in that do not touch those files, then the local changes in that file stay as they are (otherwise, you would actually get an error).

So if you pulled something, and there was no conflict, but the file is still different, then it’s possible that these are just the local changes.

Running `git status` will tell you that though; it will tell you which files have uncommitted changes. You can also run `git diff` to see how the local changes not added to the index differ from the last committed state.

Comment: I did change the name of the database in the file but I also ran git stash before pulling(sorry forgot to mention that) and I never commited the change of renaming the DB name.